# How much should I pay as Sadaqah Fitr?

Tags: practical-islam, sadaqah-al-fitr

I know the following hadith:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) ordered (Muslims) to give one Sa' of dates or one Sa' of barley as Zakat-ul-Fitr. The people rewarded two Mudds of wheat as equal to that.
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari/24/108

I want to ask the precise amount in cash that this is equal to in USD for the current year. Please mention the rates as in Saudi Arabia and Iran.

Comment: There's no sadaqah of fitr, but zakat al-fitr. As sadaqah is a free donation, while zakat is prescribed!

Comment: See my new [meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3063/13438). That depends on schools of fiqh and their interpretation, starting with the interpretation what [Sa'](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sa_(Islamic_measure)&oldid=1163391950) and mudd actually are, there are many of them.

Comment: 2.7 kg of staple food per person that you eat, To be given after sunset of 27th/28th ramadaan and before eid prayer to poor muslims

Comment: Do you follow a certain school of thought? The hanafi school basically allows you to pay with money instead of food, while the other madhabs do not. There are some different of opinions within the madhabs, but for instance, madhab maliki, the most "accurate" opinion is that one may not give money instead of food; see here in [arabic - سعيد الكملي](https://youtu.be/Uzp0atnhkqU?t=3m34s) while this is true, the moroccans tend to give their zakat ul fitr with money (while they follow madhab maliki), they follow this [fatwa](https://goo.gl/pqXejM), @Medi1Saif could correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Kilise when i was still living in Morocco we never payed money, but lately it became established the fatwa you pointed at is if i've remember well 7 years old.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the amount of Sadaqah Fitr is equivalent to one Sa'a of food, which is a measure of volume equal to approximately 3.5 pounds or 1.6 kilograms of rice, flour, or other staple food. The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) recommended giving Sadaqah Fitr in the form of food, but it is also permissible to give its equivalent value in cash to those in need.

The current recommended amount of Sadaqah Fitr for 2023 is estimated to be around $10 to $15 per person, depending on the cost of basic food items in your area. However, it's important to note that the amount of Sadaqah Fitr may vary depending on local circumstances and can be increased based on one's ability and willingness to give more.

Ultimately, the intention behind giving Sadaqah Fitr should be to please Allah and help those in need, so it's important to give according to one's means and with a pure heart.

Comment: As [Sa'a  الصاع](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sa_(Islamic_measure)&oldid=1163391950) is a volume not weight, so the weight of what can have the volume of one Sa'a depends on the kind of food you use a few potatoes could fill a volume many kg of rice could fill.

Answer (score -1):

The best is go to market near you and check how much 2.25 kg of wheat flour costs. Now that amount is MINIMUM fitrana wajib for every family member. If you want to pay more for more reward from Allah you can calculate for barley, dates, raisins or cheese.

See more [here](https://www.al-islam.org/articles/frequently-asked-questions-zakat-al-fitrah)